# Check and set http(s)_proxy in .zshrc/.bashrc when in company network

Tags: bash, proxy, zsh

I want to use my doftiles in my private network (with private computer) and in the company network (with company computer(s)). Currently I do

```
export http_proxy=http://proxy-company.com:8080
export https_proxy=$http_proxy
```

in my .zshrc/.bashrc file, but this leads to problem when using in my home network with my private computer.

Is there a way of to detecting that I'm in the company network and then do something like this in the .zshrc/.bashrc file (pseudo code)

```
if COMPANY_NETWORK
then
    export http_proxy=http://proxy-company.com:8080
    export https_proxy=$http_proxy
fi
```

**EDIT:**

This seems to work for me (Thanks to @Philippe and @mattst)

```
if ping -c 1 proxy-company.com &> /dev/null
then
    export http_proxy=http://proxy-company.com:8080
    export https_proxy=$http_proxy
fi
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: An easy way is to find a directory which exists only on company machines, and do `if test -d only-in-company ...`

Comment: @Philippe Presumably, this is for a laptop that changes networks, not a file that lives on a computer that is only used from one network or another.

Comment: @chepner, Agreed, OP didn't give any precision. Most companies do not allow personal laptop to connect to their corporate network.

Comment: We have a server in the company where tools a stored, but this server is not mounted to the company computers by default. Would it be possible to "ping" for this server/folder in the if statement?

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of ways to do that. Personally I'd probably use the `hostname` command.

```
#!/bin/bash

hostname=$(hostname)
if [ "$hostname" = "CompanyComputersHostName" ]; then
    echo "Do what you want"
fi
```

Depending on your circumstances, Philippe's suggestion of checking for the existence of a specific directory is perfectly reasonable although by preference I would create a file (probably hidden) and check to see if that exists.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -f "~/.incompany" ]; then
    echo "The ~/.incompany file exists"
fi

if [ -d "~/DirName" ]; then
    echo "The ~/DirName directory exists"
fi
```

**EDIT:**

In light of your comment you could check for your private computers and assume that any hostname that does not match must be one of the company computers.

```
#!/bin/bash

host=$(hostname)

if [ "$host" = "Private_01" -o "$host" = "Private_02" -o "$host" = "Private_03" ]; then
    echo "This is one of the private computers"
else
    echo "This must be one of the company computers"
fi
```

Comment: Your host name doesn't necessarily change based on the network you connect to, nor does your file system.

Comment: @chepner Actually the question has been edited and now says that the same config files are to be used on 2 different computers; a "private network (with private computer) and in the company network (with company computer)".

Comment: Maybe hostname is a solution, but I have "many different computers" and this would mean I need to add every host name to the dotfiles?

Comment: Mhh, I personally don't like checking for a hidden file, because then there is a extra step need to add this file.

Comment: @ge45mue You could use `hostname` to check for your private computer(s) and assume that any hostname that does not match must be one of the company computers. I will edit my answer...